# Getting cropped Image from camera in iphone

Tags: iphone

I am working on a app where i need to get a image from camera but before that i want to allow cropping of the image. I am using UIImagePickerControllerCropRect in UiImagePicker to get the cropped rectangle. I am able to get the original image from the picker but i am not able to crop it using UIImagePickerControllerCropRect. Can someone help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this support question is similar http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?threadID=1808549

Answer (score -1):

Try using Below code

Use Below mentioned Delegate Method to get Image

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)image editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo {

//you will get image here which is already cropped... 
// This will work iOS 3.2 or later

}
```

Hope this will work for you. Though I haven't tried full code yet But it is giving me scaled Size